# grouping by id and counting duplicates with XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, grouping, counting

I have below source XML that I'm able to group by id and count the duplicates:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<cases>
    <case id="1" cont="">
        <serial>111</serial>        
    </case>
    <case id="1" cont="">
        <serial>111</serial>
    </case>
    <case id="2" cont="">
        <serial>222</serial>
    </case>
</cases>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="caseKey" match="case" use="@id"/>

<xsl:template match="cases">
    <output>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|case[generate-id()=generate-id(key('caseKey', @id)[1])]"/>
    </output>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="case">
    <xsl:element name="id">
        <xsl:attribute name="val"><xsl:value-of select="@id"></xsl:value-of></xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:element name="duplicates">
            <xsl:value-of select="count(key('caseKey', @id))-1"></xsl:value-of>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:element>      
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/cases">
    <output>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="case" group-by="@id">
            <xsl:element name="id">
                <xsl:attribute name="val"><xsl:value-of select="@id"></xsl:value-of></xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:element name="duplicates">
                    <xsl:value-of select="count(current-group())-1"></xsl:value-of>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:element> 
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </output>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<output>
   <id val="1">
      <duplicates>1</duplicates>
   </id>
   <id val="2">
      <duplicates>0</duplicates>
   </id>
</output>
```

Now, my challenge is that one case can continue in another case and for that `cont` attribute will have values like `1 | 2` and `2 | 2` making that case unique, so far I haven't take into consideration the `cont` attribute for the key, but now I think I have to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<cases>
    <case id="1" cont="1 | 2">
        <serial>111</serial>        
    </case>
    <case id="1" cont="2 | 2">
        <serial>111</serial>
    </case>
    <case id="2" cont="">
        <serial>222</serial>
    </case>
    <case id="3" cont="">
        <serial>333</serial>
    </case>
    <case id="3" cont="">
        <serial>333</serial>
    </case>
    <case id="1" cont="1 | 2">
        <serial>111</serial>        
    </case>
    <case id="1" cont="2 | 2">
        <serial>111</serial>
    </case>
    <case id="4" cont="1 | 2">
        <serial>444</serial>        
    </case>
    <case id="4" cont="2 | 2">
        <serial>444</serial>
    </case>
</cases>
```

For above sample XML the expected output should be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<output>
   <id val="1">
      <duplicates>1</duplicates>
   </id>
   <id val="2">
      <duplicates>0</duplicates>
   </id>
   <id val="3">
      <duplicates>1</duplicates>
   </id>
   <id val="4">
      <duplicates>0</duplicates>
   </id>
</output>
```

**Explanation:**

- A case will be considered duplicated if the same `id` is present in multiple cases but `cont` is empty (ref: case id=3)
- A case will be considered unique if the same `id` is present in multiple cases but `cont` is not empty (ex: 1 | 2, 2 | 2) (ref: case id=4)
- A case will be considered duplicated if the same `id` along with `cont` values are present in multiple cases (ref: case id=1)

**Further explanation on duplicates:**

The below is a duplicated because the same id appears two times and cont is blank:

```
<case id="1" cont="">
    <serial>111</serial>        
</case>
<case id="1" cont="">
    <serial>111</serial>
</case>

<output>
   <id val="1">
      <duplicates>1</duplicates>
   </id>
</output>
```

Now the below itself is not a duplicate because the same id can be in multiple pages/cases, and for that the same id along with cont has to be present:

```
<case id="1" cont="1 | 2">
    <serial>111</serial>        
</case>
<case id="1" cont="2 | 2">
    <serial>111</serial>
</case>

<output>
   <id val="1">
      <duplicates>0</duplicates>
   </id>
</output>
```

The above will be considered unique. Now, the above can also be duplicated if the same appears again, like below example:

```
<case id="1" cont="1 | 2">
    <serial>111</serial>        
</case>
<case id="1" cont="2 | 2">
    <serial>111</serial>
</case>
<case id="1" cont="1 | 2">
    <serial>111</serial>        
</case>
<case id="1" cont="2 | 2">
    <serial>111</serial>
</case>

<output>
   <id val="1">
      <duplicates>1</duplicates>
   </id>
</output>
```

For above scenario, even though there are two `<case id="1" cont="1 | 2">` and two `<case id="1" cont="2 | 2">` the count of duplicates at the end is not two because that case id is the same but split in two. See below example:

```
(Case id=1 split in 3 pages - below 3 entries are considered only one - The entire block)
<case id="1" cont="1 | 3">
    <serial>111</serial>        
</case>
<case id="1" cont="2 | 3">
    <serial>111</serial>
</case>
<case id="1" cont="3 | 3">
    <serial>111</serial>
</case>

(Duplicated case id=1 same as above - This one (the entire block) is the one that counts as the duplicated)
<case id="1" cont="1 | 3">
    <serial>111</serial>        
</case>
<case id="1" cont="2 | 3">
    <serial>111</serial>
</case>
<case id="1" cont="3 | 3">
    <serial>111</serial>
</case>

<output>
   <id val="1">
      <duplicates>1</duplicates>
   </id>
</output>
```

How can I achieve this in either XSLT 1.0 or XSLT 2.0?

Comment: I'm struggling to understand your logic. You have two items with `id="1", cont="1|2"`, and you have two items with `id="1", cont="2|2"`. I can't see what the logic is that produces `<id val="1"><duplicates>1</duplicates></id>` in the output.

Comment: Thanks for giving more explanation. But in your data you have 1 duplicate of id="1", cont="1|2", and 1 duplicate of id="1", cont="2|2", so I don't understand why `<duplicates>` in the answer is 1 rather than 2.

Comment: @MichaelKay thank you for taking the time to analyze the question. Regarding your question, just keep in mind that `id=1, cont=1|2 and id=1, cont=2|2` is one occurrence split in two cases, and the other occurrence of the same thing is the duplicated. Please refer to `Further explanation on duplicates` in my post.

Comment: Sorry, you're still not making yourself clear.

Comment: @MichaelKay I guess I'm not able to explain myself :) Please see again the updated post to see if it clarifies what I need. Otherwise can you please at least show me how to group them and count the duplicates as you understand it? From there I might be able to accommodate your answer to what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have consistent input data (meaning the `cont` is either `''` or the are consistent sequences of `1 | n`, `2 | n`, .., `n | n`), I would think it suffices to group the `case`s with `cont` being empty and the ones where `n | n`; with XSLT 3 that translates into e.g.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    expand-text="yes"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-skip"/>

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="cases">
    <output>
      <xsl:for-each-group 
          select="case[@cont = '' or count(distinct-values(tokenize(@cont, '\s*\|\s*'))) = 1]" 
          composite="yes" 
          group-by="if (@cont = '') then (@id, '') else (@id, tokenize(@cont, '\s*\|\s*')[2])">
        <val id="{@id}">
          <duplicates>{count(current-group()) - 1}</duplicates>
        </val>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
    </output>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

In XSLT 2:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="2.0">
   
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="cases">
    <output>
      <xsl:for-each-group 
          select="case[@cont = '' or count(distinct-values(tokenize(@cont, '\s*\|\s*'))) = 1]" 
          group-by="@id">
        <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()" group-by="if (@cont = '') then '' else tokenize(@cont, '\s*\|\s*')[2]">
          <val id="{@id}">
            <duplicates>
              <xsl:value-of select="count(current-group()) - 1"/>                 
            </duplicates>
          </val>           
        </xsl:for-each-group>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
    </output>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```