# Output available content from Grouped elements using XSLT 2.0

Tags: xml, xslt, counting, xslt-grouping

Following the solution provided to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76654821/808891) (credits to: `Martin Honnen`) where I needed to group the elements in the XML by the `id` and counting the duplicates based on some rules.

Now I'm having an issue with the same grouped elements that have different content, which is expected, that for the same `case id` with `cont="n | n"` to have a content in one page that is not going to be present in the other.

**Source XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<cases>
    <case id="1" cont="1 | 2">
        <serial>111</serial>
        <content total="10">
          <misc val="5" />
          <misc val="5" />
        </content>
    </case>
    <case id="1" cont="2 | 2">
        <serial>111</serial>
        <message>this is a note 1</message>
    </case>
    <case id="2" cont="">
        <serial>222</serial>
        <content total="8">
          <misc val="3" />
          <misc val="5" />
        </content>
        <message>this is a note 2</message>
    </case>
</cases>
```

**XSLT 2.0:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
                xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
                exclude-result-prefixes="#all" 
                version="2.0">
                
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="cases">
    <output>
        <xsl:for-each-group 
            select="case[@cont = '' or count(distinct-values(tokenize(@cont, '\s*\|\s*'))) = 1]" 
            group-by="@id">
            <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()" group-by="if (@cont = '') then '' else tokenize(@cont, '\s*\|\s*')[2]">
                <val id="{@id}">
                    <duplicates>
                        <xsl:value-of select="count(current-group()) - 1"/>
                    </duplicates>
                    <content total="{content/@total}">
                        <xsl:for-each select="content/misc">
                            <item>
                                <xsl:value-of select="@val"/>
                            </item>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </content>
                    <message val="{message}" />
                </val>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </output>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Expected output:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<output>
   <val id="1">
      <duplicates>0</duplicates>
      <content total="10">
         <item>5</item>
         <item>5</item>
      </content>
      <message val="this is a note 1"/>
   </val>
   <val id="2">
      <duplicates>0</duplicates>
      <content total="8">
         <item>3</item>
         <item>5</item>
      </content>
      <message val="this is a note 2"/>
   </val>
</output>
```

Right now the content in the output for `id="1"` is coming empty: `<content total=""/>`. I guess some changes need to be done to the grouping piece because I was testing showing the content of what is coming in the grouping and the content from `case id="1"` is not coming at all.

What changes do I need to do in order for the same `case id` with `cont="n | n"` to have all the content present in all the pages?

**From the proposed solution:**

**Source XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<cases>
    <case id="2" cont="">
        <serial>222</serial>
        <content total="8">
          <misc val="3" />
          <misc val="5" />
        </content>
        <message>this is a note 2</message>
    </case>
    <case id="1" cont="1 | 2">
        <serial>111</serial>
        <content total="10">
          <misc val="5" />
          <misc val="5" />
        </content>
    </case>
    <case id="1" cont="2 | 2">
        <serial>111</serial>
        <message>this is a note 1</message>
    </case>
    <case id="2" cont="">
        <serial>222</serial>
        <content total="8">
          <misc val="3" />
          <misc val="5" />
        </content>
        <message>this is a note 2</message>
    </case>
</cases>
```

**Output:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<output>
   <val id="2">
      <duplicates>1</duplicates>
      <content total="8 10">
         <item>3</item>
         <item>5</item>
         <item>5</item>
         <item>5</item>
      </content>
      <message val="this is a note 2"/>
   </val>
   <val id="1">
      <duplicates>0</duplicates>
      <content total="8 10">
         <item>3</item>
         <item>5</item>
         <item>5</item>
         <item>5</item>
      </content>
      <message val="this is a note 1"/>
   </val>
</output>
```

This other input data not working:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<cases>
    <case id="1" cont="1 | 2">
        <serial>111</serial>
        <content total="10">
          <misc val="5" />
          <misc val="5" />
        </content>
    </case>
    <case id="1" cont="2 | 2">
        <serial>111</serial>
        <message>this is a note 1</message>
    </case>
    <case id="1" cont="1 | 2">
        <serial>111</serial>
        <content total="10">
          <misc val="5" />
          <misc val="5" />
        </content>
    </case>
    <case id="1" cont="2 | 2">
        <serial>111</serial>
        <message>this is a note 1</message>
    </case>
    <case id="2" cont="">
        <serial>222</serial>
        <content total="8">
          <misc val="3" />
          <misc val="5" />
        </content>
        <message>this is a note 2</message>
    </case>
</cases>
```

**Output:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<output>
   <val id="1">
      <duplicates>1</duplicates>
      <content total="10 10">
         <item>5</item>
         <item>5</item>
         <item>5</item>
         <item>5</item>
      </content>
      <message val="this is a note 1"/>
   </val>
   <val id="2">
      <duplicates>0</duplicates>
      <content total="8">
         <item>3</item>
         <item>5</item>
      </content>
      <message val="this is a note 2"/>
   </val>
</output>
```

Now then content is getting duplicated for the duplicated elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With XSLT 3 (as supported by the current/supported version of Saxon Java, Saxon .NET, SaxonC and SaxonJS) you could use the following code: it first processes all `case`s to identify groups of cases starting with `@cont` being empty or `@cont` starting with `1 | n`. For each group the collected elements are stored in the `group` property of a map.
Then the code does the grouping from the previous solution (i.e. only looks at the `case`s with `@cont` being empty or being `n | n` (i.e. the last page). Inside of the grouping, to reference back to the other items, the code just checks in the stored sequence of the groups for the one which contains the current element, that is done with the `is` XPath node identity operator. Then all the elements are used for search `content/@total` and `content/misc`:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    expand-text="yes"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-skip"/>

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" cdata-section-elements="groups" />

  <xsl:template match="cases">
    <output>
      <xsl:variable name="groups" as="map(*)*">
          <xsl:for-each-group select="case" group-starting-with="case[@cont = '' or tokenize(@cont, '\s*\|\s*')[1] = '1']">
            <xsl:sequence select="map { 'id' : xs:integer(@id), 'pos' : position(), 'group' : current-group() }"/>
          </xsl:for-each-group>
      </xsl:variable>
      <xsl:for-each-group 
          select="case[@cont = '' or count(distinct-values(tokenize(@cont, '\s*\|\s*'))) = 1]" 
          composite="yes" 
          group-by="if (@cont = '') then (@id, '') else (@id, tokenize(@cont, '\s*\|\s*')[2])">
        <val id="{@id}">
           <duplicates>{count(current-group()) - 1}</duplicates>
           <xsl:variable name="complete-group" select="$groups[some $case in ?group satisfies current() is $case]"/>
           <content total="{$complete-group?group/content/@total}">
              <xsl:for-each select="$complete-group?group/content/misc">
                  <item>
                      <xsl:value-of select="@val"/>
                  </item>
              </xsl:for-each>
           </content>
           <message val="{message}" />
        </val>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
    </output>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I have no clear idea/description of the wanted result for total and misc if there are duplicates.

Comment: @Somebody, I have edited the answer with an explanation of the code. Your comment about `cont=""` overlaps with that edit, I will need to address that later. Is there a current input sample having both duplicated `cont=""` and `cont="n | n"` cases?

Comment: @Somebody, I have changed the code to use group-starting-with, hope that is more adequate. I have no clear description of the wanted output for total and misc if there are duplicates.

Comment: Unfortunately still getting duplicated content. Please refer to the updated post, I have changed the position for the cases, if I have a case id with `cont=""` then two cases with same id with `cont="n | n"` and finally a duplicated of the case id with `cont=""` then I get duplicated content for both in the output.

Comment: @Somebody, please check whether the edit fixes it.

Comment: Wow you are fast Martin! It seems to be working fine now, will check some other scenarios, but hopefully this is it. Much appreciated!